# How to hardcode SelectList in model?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im trying to hardcode Select list in model and then get it in View but im not getting my list, just list of System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem

Model

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("BUD")]
    public IEnumerable<string> BUD { get; set; }
    public SelectList Lista = new SelectList(new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "BU"},
        new SelectListItem  {Text = "Marketing"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Additional"},
    }, "Text");
```

view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BUD, new SelectList(Model.Lista), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: User `Model.Lista` instead of `new SelectList(Model.Lista)`.

Comment: You're creating a new SelectList from a SelectList. Either change Lista's type to be List<SelectListItem> or remove 'new SelectList' from your view as committed by @SᴇM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public List<SelectListItem> Lista = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "BU", Selected = true, Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Marketing", Selected = false, Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Addition", Selected = false, Value = "3"}
    }
```

also use `Model.Lista` instead of `new SelectList(Model.Lista)`

This Should work.